# fopen file already fopened through input command in matlab

Tags: matlab, input, fopen

I'm having troubles opening a file with different fid that is previously opened with *'Input'*.

Example:

```
fid1=fopen((input('Video: ')),'r');
fid2=fopen((input('Save as: ')),'w');
...
...
fid3=fopen('','r'); % Here I want to open the input video same as fid1
```

---

I don't know how to request returned value, in this case the name entered.

Entering `fid3=fid1` after declaration of fid1 **does not** help me.

I **don't** want to ask for the name to be input again (I.e `fid3=fopen((input('Video: ')),'r');`).

Comment: So you want to not open the file if it is already open with a previous file pointer?

Comment: im using script within function to do smth else, and i need that file identifier for the same video that is inputted (which can be various video files within same folder), and i cannot use same pointer due to iterations and integrated matlab functions that i use (like `reshape`)

Comment: To be honest, it's not really clear why you need to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want to do, you need to capture and store the filename somewhere.  I really don't think that information can be recovered from a file pointer.

Comment: yeah, thats what i did actually, like create temp files and stuff like that. But that is just bad coding, i dont wanna do that..

Comment: Maybe you could create a structure that could contain that additional information.  But since file pointers contain information for a particular access (location in file, etc.) you really can't use the same file pointer for 2 different things.  You don't need temp files, just storing of the filename returned.  A file can be accessed by more than one file pointer at a time (if you are careful).

Comment: From the documentation: `filename = fopen(fileID)` returns the file name that a previous call to `fopen` used when it opened the file specified by `fileID`.

Comment: not in this case, but in very similar one i have to use temp files.. and i know i need another pointer, hence fid3, but i cannot use it as fid3=fid1 in the beginning after declarating fid1, and i dunno how else (except asking for input again, which i dont want)

Comment: @excaza
i dont think that does what i think you mean it does, or at least when you have `Input`...

but nontheless, ive tried it, it returns '' and creates new variable

Comment: It does exactly what it says it does. 1: `fID = fopen('testbox.m')` 2: `test = fopen(fID)` Result: `test = C:\Project Data\General MATLAB\testbox.m`

Comment: all ive got is `filename = ''` , im using r2010a, maybe it depends on version then... but i believe its due to the `Input` in `fopen`

Comment: fid1 = fopen(tempname=Input('Video:'),'r');  /* would this work? */